# .net 6 Application Settings return null

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Hello i have problem with ApplicationSettings it is returning null values from porperties. Can someone tell me what am i missing or doing wrong. Code :
Program.cs
I inject appsetting here
**var appSettings = _config.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationSettings)).Get();**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using ServiceCollection = Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection;
using ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli;
using ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli.Services;
using ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli.Core.Logging.Injection;
using ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli.Core.Utils.ApplicationVersion.Injection;
using ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli.Services.Injection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var _config = builder.Configuration;
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddKrvodariteliLogging();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var _logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli.Core.Logging.ILogger>();

var appSettings = _config.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationSettings)).Get<ApplicationSettings>();
DbUpgrade db = new DbUpgrade(_logger, _config, appSettings.GeneralSettings.DatabaseBackupLocation);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRouting();
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
//builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(a => a.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    // Set Cookie properties using CookieBuilder properties†.
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(appSettings.SecuritySettings.SessionExpirationTime);
                        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                        options.LoginPath = new PathString(string.Format("/account/login"));
                        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(string.Format("/account/denied"));
                        options.LogoutPath = new PathString(string.Format("/Account/LogOff"));
                    });
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ApplicationSettings>();
builder.Services.AddUnitOfWorkFactories();
builder.Services.AddDbContexts();
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
builder.Services.AddReportsServices();
builder.Services.AddKrvodariteliLogging();
builder.Services.AddApplicationVersioning();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
//var conString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AlkRepDB");
//CustomerManagementConfigure.Configure(builder.Services, conString);
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseResponseCompression();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

My appsettings.json file.
**The "..." are for security reasones, in my app there are values**

```
{
  "LoggingConfiguration": {
    "FileLoggingConfiguration": {
      "LogFileName": "...",
      "LogFileSize": 10
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Krvodaritelstvo": "..."
  },
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    "SecuritySettings": {
      "LockoutTimeInMunutes": 5,
      "NumberOfFailedTriesForLockout": 3,
      "PasswordExpirationInDays": 70,
      "ResetPasswordTokenExperationMinutes": 15,
      "SessionExpirationTime": 20
    },
    "ReportLoggingSettings": {
      "ResultZipPassword": "..."
    },
    "GeneralSettings": {
      "LandingPage": "",
      "DatabaseBackupLocation": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

My ApplicationSettings class

```
namespace ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli
{
    public class ApplicationSettings
    {
        public SecuritySettings SecuritySettings { get; set; }
        public ReportLoggingSettings ReportLoggingSettings { get; set; }
        public GeneralSettings GeneralSettings { get; set; }
    }
    public class SecuritySettings
    {
        public int LockoutTimeInMunutes { get; set; } = 5;
        public int NumberOfFailedTriesForLockout { get; set; } = 3;
        public int PasswordExpirationInDays { get; set; } = 70;
        public int ResetPasswordTokenExperationMinutes { get; set; }
        public int SessionExpirationTime { get; set; } = 20;
    }
    public class ReportLoggingSettings
    {
        public string ResultZipPassword { get; set; }
    }
    public class GeneralSettings
    {
        public string LandingPage { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseBackupLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally my error :
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to your question, but I know from experience that you increase the chance of getting a useful answer if you take the time to prepare a [mcve]. Your example is definitely not minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure it as a service before being able to use it. I've used the following:

Create a Config class where it holds your custom configurations.

```
namespace ZbirkaNaKrvodariteli
{
    public class Config
    {
       public ApplicationSettings ApplicationSettings {get;set;}
       //... other classes ...
    }

    public class ApplicationSettings
    {
        public SecuritySettings SecuritySettings { get; set; }
        public ReportLoggingSettings ReportLoggingSettings { get; set; }
        public GeneralSettings GeneralSettings { get; set; }
    }
    public class SecuritySettings
    {
        public int LockoutTimeInMunutes { get; set; } = 5;
        public int NumberOfFailedTriesForLockout { get; set; } = 3;
        public int PasswordExpirationInDays { get; set; } = 70;
        public int ResetPasswordTokenExperationMinutes { get; set; }
        public int SessionExpirationTime { get; set; } = 20;
    }
    public class ReportLoggingSettings
    {
        public string ResultZipPassword { get; set; }
    }
    public class GeneralSettings
    {
        public string LandingPage { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseBackupLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then in your Program.cs (or Startup.cs depending on .NET version) file configure the service:

```
builder.Services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("Config"));
```

This should parse the configuration into the classes you've created. If you don't want to have a single Config file you'll just need to configure each class separately.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is strange because i already have `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ApplicationSettings>();` in my code in program class

Comment: You need to `.Configure<>()` your appsettings.json to your class. Adding the class as a singleton initializes the class but without configuring (binding) it to your appsettings it will be empty.

Comment: This seems like a good case for using Options pattern.

Comment: With any of the options are mentioned above the settings are null

Comment: From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) for your case it would look like: `ApplicationSettings options = new();` then `_config.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationSettings)).Bind(options);` and you might need to add `configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);` before you try and assign your `options` variable.